# New to PHP and I'm getting an error that I can't seem to solve

Tags: php, mysql

I'll just go ahead and get it out of the way and say that I'm pretty much completely new to PHP and MySQL. I'm still in the learning process and reading everything I can. The only real way to help you understand my issue is to give you visuals.

Here's a screencap with the error circled on the right screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl3HR.png

And here's the script:

```
<?php
$con  = mysql_connect("localhost", "********", "*********");
if (!con){
die("Cannot connect to database: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("*********",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM broken";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>SYSTEM</th>
<th>TITLE</th>
<td>
</td>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<tr class="tr5">";
echo "<td class="td5">" . $record['SYSTEM'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class="td5">" . $record['TITLE'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: `if (!con){` you forgt  `$` + you have not setup PHP or file ending is not parsed, is not `.php`

Comment: I don't see a circled error anywhere... if there is one, please copy and paste it as text into the question.

Comment: If you're just starting out with PHP and MySQL, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't use the database calls that start with `mysql_` They're in the process of being abandoned because they are insecure.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - The script is embedded in the page itself.

Comment: @OllieJones - So I should replace everything saying "mysql" with "mysqli"?

Comment: @user3293128 is the page .html or .php ?

Comment: @user3293128, either mysqli_ or PDO are good interfaces to learn. Of the two, I think PDO can do more and take you further. It's not a simple cut and paste job, it's a different interface, though.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. That's your PHP code being displayed on the screen. This is happening because you are mixing up your quotes in your strings causing the strings to terminate at unexpected times:

```
echo "<tr class="tr5">";
echo "<td class="td5">" . $record['SYSTEM'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class="td5">" . $record['TITLE'] . "</td>";
```

should be

```
echo '<tr class="tr5">';
echo '<td class="td5">' . $record['SYSTEM'] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="td5">' . $record['TITLE'] . '</td>';
```

Also use `if ($con)` instead of `if (con)`.